# C# datagridview to datagridview

Tags: c#, arrays, datagridview, casting

I have 2 datagridviews the first one datagridview1 - input 4 lists of numbers
then i get the Min from each Column(4) i want to subtract  the MinVal from datagridview1 and display in datagridview2.  Im using an array icant seem to get the data type right.
[Datagridview page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zvqc.jpg) this image shows the loops are working i want the lowest in each column to by subtracted by each value in each column. the problem is getting the array to work properly.

my problem is the error im getting  "System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'
"

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sak2i.jpg)

Im stuck with this and i know its simple. can someone help with this?

```
       // Read data in

        for (int i = 0; i < Spindles; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                

              machineRadialDataArray[i, j] = (decimal)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;

            }
        }


        
        // Display Data after Calc
        for (int i = 0; i < Spindles; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                
                dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = machineRadialDataArray[i, j] - MinValTest[j];
            }
        }
        //
```

Comment: So what was the value of that cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of casting it as a decimal, have you tried converting it? I found an old example where I did something similar.

Using system;

machineRadialDataArray[i, j] = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value);

Comment: Thank you that was it.   i tried a bunch of things and never tried that.